# Elastic search container on docker refusing connection

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to run logstash with elastic search by executing following command

```
docker run --name ls01 --net elastic -p 9600:9600 -it logstash:8.2.0 -e 'input{
   stdin{
   }
}

output{
elasticsearch{
    hosts => ["https://localhost:9200"]
    index => "hello-logstash-docker"
 }
}'
```

But elastic search is refusing connection, I am receiving following error.
Attempted to resurrect connection to dead ES instance, but got an error {:url=>"http://elasticsearch:9200/", :exception=>LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch::HttpClient::Pool::HostUnreachableError, :message=>"Elasticsearch Unreachable: [http://elasticsearch:9200/][Manticore::ResolutionFailure] elasticsearch: Name or service not known"}

I am using elasticsearch version 8.2.0

Comment: You need to expose port 9200 as well. You have only 9600

Comment: I already started elastic search container on port 9200